# Can't get the newly created user in the list of all users

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I sent a request to
/d2l/api/lp/1.30/users/
and created new student.

This is my request params

```
{
  "OrgDefinedId": 'testId',
  "FirstName": 'testUser222',
  "MiddleName": '',
  "LastName": 'LastName',
  "ExternalEmail":'xxx@xxx.io',
  "UserName": 'Sam',
  "RoleId": '110',
  "IsActive": true,
  "SendCreationEmail": true
}
```

I can get this user using get request
`/d2l/api/lp/1.30/users/344`

I also activated this user by email and set new password.
I can login as this user at LMS.

But, i can't get this user using this request

`/d2l/api/lp/1.30/users/`

This user is not in the general list of users

What have I done wrong? Maybe I need some other additional request in order for it to be displayed in the general list of users?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referencing this route - https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-users-

In order to have the user included in this call's response your api user account needs to have the "Users - Search for 'xxx-role'" permission enabled.

This route does page its response, so you may have to page through the response to find the specific user.

This route does support query parameter filtering, which will reduce the number of users included in the response.

Comment: Good day. Thanks for helping me understand the API. The problem is that I see this user in the list of users when I go to the admin page on whose behalf I am making a request. And, as I said, I can get it by id. I tried to search through the list of users who are returned to me by request https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-users-

But he is not there, unlike other students (who have the same role)

Comment: Is the response paged?

Comment: This is response body

{
 "PagingInfo": {
  "Bookmark": "314",
  "HasMoreItems": true
 },
 "Items": [
  {
   "OrgId": 6606,
   "UserId": 171,
   "FirstName": "D2L.Demo",
   "MiddleName": "",
   "LastName": "Instructor",
   "UserName": "Demo.Instructor",
   "ExternalEmail": null,
   "OrgDefinedId": "Demo.Instructor",
   "UniqueIdentifier": "Demo.Instructor",
   "Activation": {
    "IsActive": true
   },
   "DisplayName": "D2L.Demo Instructor",
   "LastAccessedDate": "2019-01-09T17:03:52.540Z"
  },

Comment: Thanks. Please read this documentation - https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/apicall.html?highlight=bookmark#Api.PagedResultSet

"PagingInfo": { "Bookmark": "314", "HasMoreItems": true }

If HasMoreItems is true, then it means that the response has another page of data available. To get the next page you have to call the API route again, but add the paging bookmark value in the query string like this...

/d2l/api/lp/1.30/users/?bookmark=314